# Is a quantum theory that is indigenously quantum mechanical a real possibility?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

The general approach to Quantum Mechanics is that one first takes a classical system and then quantise to obtain a quantum mechanical system. This holds for QM itself, and QFT such as QED and QCD and also more esoteric theories such as string theory and LQG.

However, this strikes me as being a little backward. Surely, if quantum mechanics is a fundamental theory, and every indication suggests that it is, one ought to *begin* with a quantum mechanical system and then derive a classical world from it. That is we ought to have a Quantum Mechanics that is indigenously Quantum mechanical.

This seems to me a basic and fundamental question in physics, and I'm wondering what philosophically minded physicists, which of course, all good physicists should be (and have been in the past), have addressed this question in any substantial way (I do know of Causal Set Theory as one particular attempt) - or are they still busy obsessing (or spinning!) over 'so-called Quantum Supremacy?'

Comment: Quantum mechanics is not a fundamental theory, and physicists do not suggest that it is. Not even QFT is, both have to be reconciled with GR, and string theory and LQG are the proposals for that. But the "general approach" to QM *does* start from QM itself, and classical laws are derived in the limit. Quantization of classical systems is just a heuristic for guessing correct quantum models in specific cases, not a "general approach", and not "deriving" QM from CM.

Comment: @conifold: Until QM mechanics *IS* reconciled its considered as a fundamental theory. This is why QM has been reconciled with SR and that is QFT. The heuristic of quantisation is exactly what physicists do to actually to find a quantum system, it's not covered by any abstract system of axioms. Tus my question.

Comment: @conifold: by the way, the term for a non-fundamental theory of physics is an effective theory, but I didn't bother to put that assuming that people would understand what I meant instead picking pedantic holes in it.

Comment: Physical modeling begins from a phenomenon, which is initially described in colloquial or observational terms, not even classical mechanical. Classical model to be quantized is a stepping stone. A path from phenomenon to a model, of which quantization is a part, is not up to a "fundamental theory", it is heuristic. Only once the model is formulated can it "derive the world" theoretically, and be tested. It functioned this way in CM, QM and other scientific theories, the method is hypothetico-deductive, and the hypothetical part isn't meant to be deductive.

Comment: @Conifold: Hmmm...and doesn't the measurement postulate mean that all measurements are classical? And given that the other foundational theory is GR and that is also classical then all measurements are classical and not quantum. Not sure why you feel you need to add the rest of your word-salad - it doesn't add up.

Comment: No, it is does not mean that. "*Whether you can observe a thing or not depends on the theory which you use. It is the theory which decides what can be observed*", Einstein. Measurements and observations are what the theory used to interpret them says they are. If it is QM they are "quantum". And before classical mechanics they were not "classical" either, as Aristotelian interpretations show.

Comment: @Conifold: They do actually: Measurements are classical by definition, because measuring instruments are classical. Do you mind me asking what your qualifications are for commenting on physics, I have a couple of degrees, one in Physics from Imperial College in London, and another from Oxford, in mathematics? I assume you do have an education in physics given you've named yourself after a concept in string theory - but names do not equal education, credentials or qualifications.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Given your credentials couldn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @ben: I've certainly got my own take on it ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah There's no rule against answering your own question. I'd like to hear your take on it.

Comment: @Ben: My take on it is that it is an important problem and one that does not get enough attention. It's because it doesn't get enough attention that I asked the question.  The one approach to it that I do know of is causal set theory but I don't know very much about it. However, one important result is that there time is real unlike in GR where the spacetime manifold is given - I mean the past, present & future all have the same ontological status.

Answer (score 1):

> The general approach to Quantum Mechanics is that one first takes a classical system and then quantise to obtain a quantum mechanical system.

Quantisation is not an algorithm. It consists of applying principles of quantum theory to coming up with a theory whose equations bear some faint resemblance to the equations of a classical theory and that gives similar predictions when the system decoheres. See

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0304202

> This seems to me a basic and fundamental question in physics, and I'm wondering what philosophically minded physicists, which of course, all good physicists should be (and have been in the past), have addressed this question in any substantial way (I do know of Causal Set Theory as one particular attempt) - or are they still busy obsessing over 'so-called Quantum Supremacy?'

There are obstacles to coming up with theories that start out as quantum mechanical, the main one is that physicists don't take quantum theory seriously as a description of how the world works,as David Deutsch explains here:

https://vimeo.com/5490979

Deutsch has tried to do some work on non-quantised quantum theories, such as qubit field theory:

https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401024

Comment: -1: for qubit dogmatism.

Comment: It would be -1000 for double-dutch and double-dutch dogmatism.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Your comments are rather cryptic. Could you explain or link to an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

> Surely, if quantum mechanics is a fundamental theory, and every indication suggests that it is, one ought to begin with a quantum mechanical system and then derive a classical world from it.
>
> …
>
> [W]hat philosophically minded physicists … have addressed this … ?

Sean Carroll is a philosophically minded physicist, and he does take this approach. I am not familiar with (and not equipped to understand) his technical papers, but his newest book (for a broader audience), [Something Deeply Hidden](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/somethingdeeplyhidden/) seems to take the approach you are describing. There is also has an episode of his podcast about [Finding Gravity Within Quantum Mechanics](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/podcast/2019/09/09/63-solo-finding-gravity-within-quantum-mechanics/).

It sounds like he is talking about exactly what you are talking about, though he connects this «QM first»-approach to an "Everettian" way of understanding QM. The following is from the podcast:

> When we construct a quantum mechanical theory, whether it’s a theory of a single particle or the standard model of particle physics or whatever you wanna think about, we typically start with a classical theory and then we quantize it.
> …
> But if you are a good Everettian, you think that even that very first move is probably kind of wrong-headed because the world isn’t classical. Classical mechanics is not there at the foundation of reality, the world is fundamentally quantum.

The striking similarity with the way you formulate your question, and Carroll's explicit ambition to «derive spacetime itself from something purely quantum mechanical», makes me think that the technical papers he links to in [Finding Gravity Within Quantum Mechanics](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/podcast/2019/09/09/63-solo-finding-gravity-within-quantum-mechanics/) might contribute to an answer.

Comment: Although the papers are 'technical', Sean Carroll himself admits that 'All of this stuff is extremely speculative...'; it's always important to add this qualification in cases like this ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah Sure, but if the question is whether the relevant understanding of QM is _possible_, speculation is exactly what you need. Speculating in this way _is_ asking whether it is possible.

Comment: I'm not denying that, I'm pointing out when speculation is being indulged in, then speculation should be advertised as such - which by the way what exactly Sean Carroll did.